# D3 jQuery range slider does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, rangeslider

I have searched stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution for my case.
I am doing a simple interactive visualization with D3. I want to include a range slider for users to select a range. Then create a filter function that filters the data based on the selected range and updates the visualization. The range slider just does not show up in my browser (both Chrome and Safari).


Relevant code:

```
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div id="layout">
        <div id="title">
            <p>Stocks Scatterplot</p>
        </div>
        <div id="visualization">
            <div id="controls">
                <!--create the sliders here-->
                <p>Assists</p>
                    <div id="assists" class="d3-slider"></div>
                    <label for="assistamount">Assists range:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="assistamount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;
                    font-weight:bold;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#assits").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: maxAssists,
    values:[0,maxAssists],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#assistamount").val(ui.values[0]+"-"+ui.values[1]);
      filterAssists(ui.values);}
    });
  $("#assistamount").val($("#assits").slider("values",0) + "-" + $("#assits").slider("values",1));
});
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo!!
`$("#assits")` should be `$("#assists")`.
I guess you have defined `maxAssests` before the slider definition as well.

Also use more up to date versions of jquery & ui. I got your code to work with these.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, why it should be "assests" instead of "assists"? Isn't it a variable that can be named whatever I want?

Comment: rip I had typo as well. It should be assists. I have updated my answer

Comment: I tried the more updated versions of jquery and ui but the slider still didn't show up. Can you see it on your browser?

Comment: Yep it displays. im using chrome. Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rr4d0mv3/) where i can see it note that the css is a copy of the jquery ui style sheet cause it doesnt work if I left the link in the html code. I cant see all your code but you might want to check that the stylesheet is being loaded.

Comment: That's weird though... maybe some other parts of my code blocked the slider. I'll check it. Thanks so much!